# Unable to include a search function in HTML tables

Tags: javascript, html, search

I'm trying to include a search function for a html file but I can't get it to work. The goal would be to hide every department/user that doesn't fit the criteria.

```js
// counter
var counter = 0;
// superzahl alle divs zusammen
var divLength =
  document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible").length +
  document.getElementsByClassName("infoBtn").length;

//Single aufklappen der Grauen
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  });
}

//Single aufklappen der infos
var infoColl = document.getElementsByClassName("infoBtn");
for (i = 0; i < infoColl.length; i++) {
  infoColl[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(content);
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  });
}

//array für die conten-divs
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
//array für die info buttons
var infos = document.getElementsByClassName("info");

//funktion um die content-divs zu öffnen
function openGrau() {
  for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    if (contents[i].style.display === "block") {
      contents[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      contents[i].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
//funktion um die info-buttons zu öffnen
function openInfos() {
  for (i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    if (infos[i].style.display === "block") {
      infos[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      infos[i].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  }
}

function openAll() {
  openGrau();
  openInfos();
}

function closeAll() {
  for (i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    if (infos[i].style.display === "block") {
      infos[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    }
  }
  for (j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
    if (contents[j].style.display === "block") {
      contents[j].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    }
  }
}

function openAllCloseAll() {
  if (counter >= divLength / 2) {
    closeAll();
  } else if (counter <= divLength / 2) {
    openAll();
  }
}

var toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggle");
toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  openGrau();
});

var almightyBtn = document.getElementById("toggleall");
almightyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  openAllCloseAll();
});

var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  closeAll();
});

function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("csv");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      found = false;
    } else {
      if (tr[i].id != 'csv') {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 80%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 15%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 15%;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* border: none; */
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.csv {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="top">
      <input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchTable()' type='text' placeholder="Suche">
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="toggle">users</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="toggleall">Toggle All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </tr>
  </div><button class="collapsible"> Department1 </button>
  <div class="content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">User</th>
          <th scope="col">Client</th>
          <th scope="col">Datum</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> User </td>
          <td> client#1 </td>
          <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:27 </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="#client#1_637359227584900619">Info</button>
            <div id="client#1_637359227584900619" class="collapse info">
              <table class="csv">
                <colgroup>
                  <col/>
                  <col/>
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                  <th>user</th>
                  <th>User1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>client</td>
                  <td>client#1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>ip adresse</td>
                  <td>192.168.1.x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>mac</td>
                  <td>xxxxx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>ou</td>
                  <td>Department2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                  <td>09/15/2020 17:00:19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>windows</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>build</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>update</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>laufwerk</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>hdd_size</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>hdd_free</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>printer</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>M283fdw</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Canon </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>LOGO</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>weiss</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                  <td>Office</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>dc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>home$\user</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
        </tr>
        <td> user2 </td>
        <td> client#2 </td>
        <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:33 </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="pc_637359227585210650">Info</button>
          <div id="pc_637359227585210650" class="collapse info">
            <table class="csv">
              <colgroup>
                <col/>
                <col/>
              </colgroup>
              <tr>
                <th>user</th>
                <th>user2</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>client</td>
                <td>clien#2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ip adresse</td>
                <td>192.168.1.xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>mac</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ou</td>
                <td>Department</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>windows</td>
                <td>asdf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>build</td>
                <td>fdsa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>sdaf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>laufwerk</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hdd_size</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hdd_free</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>printer</td>
                <td>Farbe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Canon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>raum</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Canon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                <td>Office</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>huhu</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>haha</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </tr>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </tr>
    </div><button class="collapsible"> Department2 </button>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col">Client</th>
            <th scope="col">Datum</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> user3 </td>
            <td> client#3 </td>
            <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:16 </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="client#3_637359227585640686">Info</button>
              <div id="client#3_637359227585640686" class="collapse info">
                <table class="csv">
                  <colgroup>
                    <col/>
                    <col/>
                  </colgroup>
                  <tr>
                    <th>user</th>
                    <th>user#3</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>client</td>
                    <td>client#3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ip adresse</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>mac</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ou</td>
                    <td>Department</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>windows</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>build</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>update</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>laufwerk</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>hdd_size</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>hdd_free</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>printer</td>
                    <td>Canon</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>SW</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>logo</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                    <td>ung</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>\asdf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>asdf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>hadsf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>huhu</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
          </tr>
      </table>
      </tr>
```

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I'm very sorry for that but if I would know what's wrong, I would be more specific. My search function doesn't work at all. Does nothing and I'm not sure where to begin with.

Comment: @kuhlimuh Liam asked you to tell us, what you are trying to achieve, what we should do (where to click, etc) to reproduce the issue and what the expected result should be

Answer (score 1):

Your table is missing the `id` attribute that you are querying in this row:
`table = document.getElementById("csv");`

`<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="csv">` seems to fix the issue

```js
// counter
var counter = 0;
// superzahl alle divs zusammen
var divLength =
  document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible").length +
  document.getElementsByClassName("infoBtn").length;

//Single aufklappen der Grauen
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  });
}

//Single aufklappen der infos
var infoColl = document.getElementsByClassName("infoBtn");
for (i = 0; i < infoColl.length; i++) {
  infoColl[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(content);
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  });
}

//array für die conten-divs
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
//array für die info buttons
var infos = document.getElementsByClassName("info");

//funktion um die content-divs zu öffnen
function openGrau() {
  for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    if (contents[i].style.display === "block") {
      contents[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      contents[i].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
//funktion um die info-buttons zu öffnen
function openInfos() {
  for (i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    if (infos[i].style.display === "block") {
      infos[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    } else {
      infos[i].style.display = "block";
      counter++;
    }
  }
}

function openAll() {
  openGrau();
  openInfos();
}

function closeAll() {
  for (i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
    if (infos[i].style.display === "block") {
      infos[i].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    }
  }
  for (j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
    if (contents[j].style.display === "block") {
      contents[j].style.display = "none";
      counter--;
    }
  }
}

function openAllCloseAll() {
  if (counter >= divLength / 2) {
    closeAll();
  } else if (counter <= divLength / 2) {
    openAll();
  }
}

var toggleBtn = document.getElementById("toggle");
toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  openGrau();
});

var almightyBtn = document.getElementById("toggleall");
almightyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  openAllCloseAll();
});

var resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  closeAll();
});

function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("csv");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      found = false;
    } else {
      if (tr[i].id != 'csv') {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 80%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 15%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 15%;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* border: none; */
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.csv {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="top">
      <input id='myInput' onkeyup='searchTable()' type='text' placeholder="Suche">
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="toggle">users</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="toggleall">Toggle All</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </tr>
  </div><button class="collapsible"> Department1 </button>
  <div class="content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="csv">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">User</th>
          <th scope="col">Client</th>
          <th scope="col">Datum</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> User </td>
          <td> client#1 </td>
          <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:27 </td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="#client#1_637359227584900619">Info</button>
            <div id="client#1_637359227584900619" class="collapse info">
              <table class="csv">
                <colgroup>
                  <col/>
                  <col/>
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                  <th>user</th>
                  <th>User1</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>client</td>
                  <td>client#1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>ip adresse</td>
                  <td>192.168.1.x</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>mac</td>
                  <td>xxxxx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>ou</td>
                  <td>Department2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                  <td>09/15/2020 17:00:19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>windows</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>build</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>update</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>laufwerk</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>hdd_size</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>hdd_free</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>printer</td>
                  <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>M283fdw</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Canon </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>LOGO</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>weiss</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                  <td>Office</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>dc</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>home$\user</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
        </tr>
        <td> user2 </td>
        <td> client#2 </td>
        <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:33 </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="pc_637359227585210650">Info</button>
          <div id="pc_637359227585210650" class="collapse info">
            <table class="csv">
              <colgroup>
                <col/>
                <col/>
              </colgroup>
              <tr>
                <th>user</th>
                <th>user2</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>client</td>
                <td>clien#2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ip adresse</td>
                <td>192.168.1.xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>mac</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ou</td>
                <td>Department</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>windows</td>
                <td>asdf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>build</td>
                <td>fdsa</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>update</td>
                <td>sdaf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>laufwerk</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hdd_size</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hdd_free</td>
                <td>xx</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>printer</td>
                <td>Farbe</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Canon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>raum</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Canon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                <td>Office</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>huhu</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>haha</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </tr>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </tr>
    </div><button class="collapsible"> Department2 </button>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col">Client</th>
            <th scope="col">Datum</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> user3 </td>
            <td> client#3 </td>
            <td> 09/16/2020 09:30:16 </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm infoBtn" data-target="client#3_637359227585640686">Info</button>
              <div id="client#3_637359227585640686" class="collapse info">
                <table class="csv">
                  <colgroup>
                    <col/>
                    <col/>
                  </colgroup>
                  <tr>
                    <th>user</th>
                    <th>user#3</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>client</td>
                    <td>client#3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ip adresse</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>mac</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>ou</td>
                    <td>Department</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>LastDomainSync</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>windows</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>build</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>update</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>laufwerk</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>hdd_size</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>hdd_free</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>printer</td>
                    <td>Canon</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>SW</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>logo</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>HP</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>netzlaufwerke</td>
                    <td>ung</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>\asdf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>asdf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>hadsf</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>huhu</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
          </tr>
      </table>
      </tr>
```